# What does "go pop" mean?

Tags: meaning

Here's an excerpt that I read:

"This is my stop. Got to get off. I may go pop. Excuse me, excuse me"

What does "go pop" mean in this context?

Comment: Hi Rafael, would you care to share where this quote comes from? Thanks!

Comment: [Interpreting song lyrics](http://www.leoslyrics.com/splendora/you-re-standing-on-my-neck-lyrics/) is Off Topic. But for what it's worth, those words are mostly chosen for the alliterative effect.

Comment: It comes from this song: http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080529044133AA6cCXE

Comment: @Rafael Vega: Don't worry about it. Song lyrics aren't *blatantly* OT, imho. If, for example, you hadn't understood the *first* two sentences in your fragment, someone could explain the "bus stop" metaphor with absolute certainty (people actually say that with a literal meaning). But people never *literally* "go pop", and it's not a common metaphorical usage either - so any answers you get will be at least somewhat subjective, and there's no "definitive" answer. JAM's first paragraph is a good enough interpretation, and given ELU shouldn't be doing Lit. Crit., I think that should be enough.

Comment: ...having said all that, I see I'm the only one who's voted to close so far. At least some of the mods will have already looked at this question and *not* decided to close it. Which doesn't imply much, since they tend to leave it to the collective decision of the rest of us unless the question is a really bad fit to the site (which yours isn't). You've asked in good faith, so you shouldn't feel "responsible" or "at fault" even if it does get closed - and at this rate, it probably won't!

Comment: @FumbleFingers fwiw I too think this question is a good fit for this site. "Go pop" is a recognisable phrase in English, yet its meaning is not blatantly obvious.

Comment: This is a bit late to the above comment discussion, but I just wanted to note that there's a difference between interpreting song lyrics (which is off-topic) and asking what a phrase means that just happens to be in a song (which in my book, is on-topic, and is what this question seems to be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Go pop" could mean many different things. We'd really need a little more context. However, it sounds like the speaker is on a bus or commuter train and is anxious to get to the door through the crowd, or else s/he may "go pop." It probably means something like "explode" or "give out" but it is clearly meant metaphorically (*I'm at the end of my tether, I can't take any more, if I don't get out of here I won't be accountable for my actions...* ).

It could come from the sound of a cork coming out of a bottle of champagne (see the first noun definition on [this page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pop)).

It could also come from the song *[Pop Goes the Weasel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_goes_the_weasel)*:

```
Half a pound of tuppenny rice,
Half a pound of treacle.
That’s the way the money goes,
Pop! goes the weasel.
```

But according to the Wikipedia page at least, it's never been clear exactly what "pop" means in the song.

Comment: What happened to the merry-go-round?

Comment: @tchrist do you mean the mulberry bush?

Comment: Yes, I meant the mulberry bush.

Comment: @tchrist there are many verses to the song, just wanted to include one for illustrative purposes. Not quite a miracle of rare device, this...

Comment: I think this answer is a complete waste of time in relation to OP's question. Just because his lyrics include *go pop*, and that nursery rhyme has *pop goes* doesn't mean there's any connection.

Comment: Thanks alot?! This song has been stuck in my head for the last 2 hours now ;-)

Comment: "I won't be accountable for my actions" sounds like a pretty good interpretation to me. Thanks!  @Jim: lol!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I included the *Pop Goes the Weasel* lyrics only because they are such a widely recognised instance of "pop" that I thought it would give extra context to the meaning of "pop" in the question. Constructive (and kind) criticism is always *most* welcome.

Comment: As a small child, I had a [jack-in-the-box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack-in-the-box) that played "Pop Goes the Weasel" as you turned the crank. There was never any doubt, to me at least, what "pop" meant in the song: it is when the jester pops out of the box!

Comment: Well as you say, even Wikipedia gives no convincing explanation of what *"Pop goes the weasel"* actually ***means***, but I seriously doubt the line was included to reference a jack-in-the-box action. I agree my first comment was out of line though - your first paragraph is as good an answer as OP could hope for. The rest still seems to me to be irrelevant, but that's no reason to downvote (nor is the fact that I don't rate the question itself). My apologies, and downvote removed.